# Get the number of MPI processes from the file

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I cannot figure out how to get the number of MPI processes that need to be ran from the file. I have a MakeFile and in my 'run' goal I have:

```
mpirun --hostfile ${HOSTFILE} ./${PROGRAM} $(input_file)
```

That's working fine but I want to specify the number of processes that need to be ran and I want to get them from the first line of this input_file. How can I do this?

For instance, the first line in input_file is 9. I therefore want to have this:

```
mpirun -n 9 --hostfile my_host_file ./program file.input
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding comments and whitespace, there's one host per line. You could strip all that other stuff and just count the number of lines. If you generate the hostfile yourself and you know it's 'clean' then `wc -l ${HOSTFILE}` should do it.

Comment: Should the hostfile be changed together with the input_file? I mean, should every change in the number of processes I want to be ran be followed by the change in hosts? Or can I declare too many hosts in the hostfile and control the number of processes by parameter -n?

Comment: I believe you can use a smaller `-n` than you have hosts in the hostfile, but it might be implementation dependent. On the one system where we did that it would take the first `-n` hosts, but this is something you should test.